# Can I use wpf mouse event replace touch event?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio-2012

My WPF project required touch screen. but now I haven't touch screen. So I use Mouse event (include Muse down, Mouse Move, Mouse up ..events) to all project. but I'm very worry when finish the project , and when use touch screen, the mouse event don't working. So my problem is :

1.Is touch event support mouse event? Am I need to change all Mouse event to Touch event in my project? (actually I'm very hope I can use the 2 event both in same time. I mean use mouse + use finger)
2.if don't support, Is there any way can easy handle the problem?

My project using .net4.0.   thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WPF MouseEvents already have an interface to handle with touch, so you dont need to make two methods.

When you touch an button it is recognized as it was a mouse click, so dont worry about this :)

You will have to implement just the "slide" touch events but not the clicked ones.

Comment: can I use the old: Mouse down + Mouse up + Mouse move event to slide? Or I must use a slide touch event?

Comment: Im afraid that you cant ;/